# An Electron Chasing Another

Tags: forces, momentum, coulombs-law

An electron is held in place in deep space. Another electron approaches with speed $v_0$. When the approaching electron is a distance $r_0$ away from the first electron, the first is set free. The electrons exert a force $F = \frac{e^2}{4\pi \epsilon r(t)^2}$ on each other, where $r(t) = r_0 - v(t)*t + u(t)*t$, $u(t)$ is the velocity of the first electron, and $v(t)$ is the velocity of the approaching electron. I want to get $v(t)$ in terms of $r_0$ and $v_0$. The initial conditions are $v(0) = v_0$ and $u(0) = 0$. Also

$$F=\frac{e^2}{4 \pi\epsilon r(t)^2} = \frac{e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon (r_0 +(u-v)t)^2}= m_e \dot{u} = -m_e\dot{v} \: \: \: \: \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:(1)$$ 
This then gives us $$\dot{u} = -\dot{v}$$. Integrating both sides and applying the initial conditions gives $$u(t) = v_0 - v(t)$$
Plugging this back into $(1)$ and simplifying we get $$\frac{-e^2}{4 \pi \epsilon m} = \dot{v} (r_0 + (v_0-2v)t)^2$$

For $r0 = 1000m$ and $v0 = 100m/s$ I get this plot for $v(t)$:
[image]

I have tried for different values of $r0$ and $v0$ and the velocity always settles for around half the initial value. Is there a reason for that? I can "feel" how the approaching electron would share half of its energy with the first electron. But what's the rigorous explanation?

Also if we plot $r(t)$ we get this plot:

[image]

, where the minimum separation is about 7 meters. Does it make physical sense that the separation change so linearly?

note: I used the NDSolve command to solve (1).

Comment: I think there must be something wrong in your analysis, because distance is not velocity multiplied by time if the velocity is changing.

Comment: $r(t) = r0 + \int_{0}^{t} (u(\tau) -v(\tau))d\tau$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you do calculations like this is to work in the centre of mass frame. The setup you describe looks like this (the convention here is that velocities to the left are positive, and velocities to the right are negative):

[image: Original]

But suppose we view the collision from a frame moving to the left at $v/2$ i.e. we have to subtract $v/2$ from all the velocities. In that case the collision looks like this:

[image: COM frame]

Note that the collision is now symmetric i.e. both electrons start with the same speed, but in opposite directions. We can now calculate what happens in the collision and then add $v/2$ back on when we've finished.

To see why the centre of mass frame makes things easy, consider your first question, what is the velocity of the green electron after the collision? because the collision is symmetrical in the centre of mass frame, the velocities after the electrons have collided and ricocheted back to a distance $r_0$ will simply be:

[image: COM frame after]

To get back to the original frame we need to add $v/2$, and when we do this we find the velocity of the red electron is now $+v$ and the velocity of the green electron is zero.

If you want the velocity as a function of distance that is also easy because we can use conservation of energy. The initial energy is:

$$ E_0 = KE + PE = \tfrac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{-v}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{kQ^2}{r_0} $$

where $m$ is the electron mass and $Q$ is the electron charge. When the distance is $r$ the energy is:

$$ E_R = \tfrac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{v(r)}{2}\right)^2 + \tfrac{1}{2}m\left(\frac{-v(r)}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{kQ^2}{r} $$

Since energy is conserved $E_0 = E_r$ and equating the two equations above gives (after some rearrangement):

$$ v^2(r) = v_0^2 + \frac{4kQ^2}{m}\left(\frac{1}{r_0} - \frac{1}{r}\right) $$

And remember to add $v/2$ back on to get back to your original frame.

If you want velocity as a function of time that still remains a bit involved. If you look at the green particle then the force on it is the Coulomb force:

$$ F = -\frac{kQ^2}{r^2} $$

and dividing by the mass gives the acceleration:

$$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = -\frac{kQ^2}{r^2} = -\frac{kQ^2}{(2x)^2} $$

because if we put the origin at the centre of mass we have $r = 2x$. Note that the acceleration of the green electron is negative because it points right. Solving this is straightforward but messy, so I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader :-) The result isn't going to be the straight line graph that you plotted.